# Decreasing derivative, so which is larger?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f'(x)$ is a differentiable decreasing function for all $x$. In each of the following pairs, which number is the larger? Give a reason for your answer.

A) $f'(5)$ and $f'(6)$

My answer is $f'(5)$ because $f'(x)$ is decreasing so we have to look at the smaller $X$ value.

B) $f''(5)$ and $0 $

I don't know but I think it is $0$

C) $ f(5 + (\Delta x)) \ $ and $ \ f(5) + f'(5) \cdot (\Delta x) $

I didn't get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A) A function $g$ is decreasing if $x \leq y$ imply $g(x) \geq g(y)$, so in your case $f'(6)\leq f'(5)$.

B) If $f'(x)$ is decreasing then $f$ is [concave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function#Properties) and thus we must have $f''(x) \leq 0$, in particular $f''(5)\leq 0$. Note that $f'$ differentiable implies that $f$ is twice differentiable. This is the second order condition for concave functions, see [here](http://mathgotchas.wordpress.com/2011/10/28/proof-of-the-second-order-condition-of-convexity/) for a proof and use the fact that $g$ convex implies $-g$ concave.

C) Since $f$ is concave, it must satisfy the first order condition for concave functions (note that $f$ is differentiable, since $f'$ is differentiable). See [here](http://mathgotchas.blogspot.de/2011/10/proof-for-first-order-condition-of.html) for a proof. In particular this imply that for every $y,x$ holds $$f(y) \leq f(x)+f'(x)(y-x)$$
Take $y = 5 + \Delta x, x = 5$, then $$f(5 + \Delta x) \leq f(5)+f'(5)(5+\Delta x-5)=f(5)+f'(5)\Delta x$$

Comment: I understand what you did in (c) and the steps you made, but I didn't get what makes you say that f(y) is lower. Sorry

Comment: @John I tried to edit my post, does it answers your question?

Comment: yes it does, thanks